# .htaccess block mysql queries in url

Tags: .htaccess

I need to write a rule that blocks a mysql query.. like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} UNION [OR]
```

but was thinking of something like

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} SELECT (.*?) FROM [OR]
```

so that one couldn't every run a query from the url.. ideas?

Thanks.. cheers -Jeremy

Comment: just don't allow any code paths to query the database without sanitising the user-passed arguments?

Comment: I'm sorry .. is that a question?  I understand that you would normal sanitize all query to prevent injections but.. lets just say for a sec that there was an error.  That is what it is about.  The one off over looked case.  So I want to just straight filter a query if in a url.  Just not a super rewrite guru here so who knows what the rule would look like was the question I pose.  thanks for the help.  Cheers -Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the anwser... So based on this..

The Data Manipulation Language (DML) and the Data Definition Language (DDL).

The query and update commands form the DML part of SQL:
 •SELECT - extracts data from a database
•UPDATE - updates data in a database
•DELETE - deletes data from a database
•INSERT INTO - inserts new data into a database

The DDL part of SQL permits database tables to be created or deleted. It also define indexes (keys), specify links between tables, and impose constraints between tables. The most important DDL statements in SQL are:
•CREATE DATABASE - creates a new database
•ALTER DATABASE - modifies a database
•CREATE TABLE - creates a new table
•ALTER TABLE - modifies a table
•DROP TABLE - deletes a table
•CREATE INDEX - creates an index (search key)
•DROP INDEX - deletes an index

So, I'm thinking this covers 99%  and it's one rule ..

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*
    ( 
        (%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)(%6C|%4C|l)(%65|%45|e)(%63|%43|c)(%74|%54|t)              #SELECT
      | (%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)(%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)(%72|%52|r)(%74|%54|t)              #INSERT
      | (%44|%64|d)(%65|%45|e)(%6C|%4C|l)(%65|%45|e)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)              #DELETE
      | (%44|%64|d)(%72|%52|r)(%4F|%6F|o)(%70|%50|p)                        #DROP
      | (%55|%75|u)(%70|%50|p)(%44|%64|d)(%41|%61|a)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)              #UPDATE
      | (%41|%61|a)(%6C|%4C|l)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)(%72|%52|r)                 #ALTER
      | (%41|%61|a)(%44|%64|d)(%44|%64|d)                               #ADD
      | (%4A|%6A|j)(%4F|%6F|o)(%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)                        #JOIN
      | (%63|%43|c)(%72|%52|r)(%65|%45|e)(%41|%61|a)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)              #CREATE
    )

    .*
    (
        (%74|%54|t)(%41|%61|a)(%42|%62|b)(%6C|%4C|l)(%65|%45|e)                     #TABLE
      | (%46|%66|f)(%72|%52|r)(%4F|%6F|o)(%4D|%6D|m)                        #FROM
      | (%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)(%74|%54|t)(%4F|%6F|o)                        #INTO
      | (%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)(%74|%54|t)                               #SET
      | (%63|%43|c)(%4F|%6F|o)(%6C|%4C|l)(%55|%75|u)(%4D|%6D|m)(%6E|%4E|n)              #COLUMN
      | (%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)(%44|%64|d)(%58|%78|e)(%72|%52|x)                 #INDEX
      | (%56|%76|v)(%69|%49|i)(%58|%78|e)(%57|%77|w)                        #VIEW
      | (%55|%75|u)(%6E|%4E|n)(%69|%49|i)(%4F|%6F|o)(%6E|%4E|n)                 #UNION 
      | (%44|%64|d)(%41|%61|a)(%74|%54|t)(%41|%61|a)(%42|%62|b)(%41|%61|a)(%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)    #DATABASE
    )
    .*
    (
        (%57|%77|w)(%48|%68|h)(%65|%45|e)(%72|%52|r)(%65|%45|e)                     #WHERE
      | (%4F|%6F|o)(%6E|%4E|n)                                  #ON
      | (%41|%61|a)(%6C|%4C|l)(%6C|%4C|l)                               #ALL
      | (.*)                                            #  ##Blank so move on 
    )
    .* [NC,OR]
```

it was tested as

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .*((%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)(%6C|%4C|l)(%65|%45|e)(%63|%43|c)(%74|%54|t)|(%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)(%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)(%72|%52|r)(%74|%54|t)|(%44|%64|d)(%65|%45|e)(%6C|%4C|l)(%65|%45|e)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)|(%44|%64|d)(%72|%52|r)(%4F|%6F|o)(%70|%50|p)|(%55|%75|u)(%70|%50|p)(%44|%64|d)(%41|%61|a)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)|(%41|%61|a)(%6C|%4C|l)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)(%72|%52|r)|(%41|%61|a)(%44|%64|d)(%44|%64|d)|(%4A|%6A|j)(%4F|%6F|o)(%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)|(%63|%43|c)(%72|%52|r)(%65|%45|e)(%41|%61|a)(%74|%54|t)(%65|%45|e)).*((%74|%54|t)(%41|%61|a)(%42|%62|b)(%6C|%4C|l)(%65|%45|e)|(%46|%66|f)(%72|%52|r)(%4F|%6F|o)(%4D|%6D|m)|(%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)(%74|%54|t)(%4F|%6F|o)|(%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)(%74|%54|t)|(%63|%43|c)(%4F|%6F|o)(%6C|%4C|l)(%55|%75|u)(%4D|%6D|m)(%6E|%4E|n)|(%69|%49|i)(%6E|%4E|n)(%44|%64|d)(%58|%78|e)(%72|%52|x)|(%56|%76|v)(%69|%49|i)(%58|%78|e)(%57|%77|w)|(%55|%75|u)(%6E|%4E|n)(%69|%49|i)(%4F|%6F|o)(%6E|%4E|n)|(%44|%64|d)(%41|%61|a)(%74|%54|t)(%41|%61|a)(%42|%62|b)(%41|%61|a)(%73|%53|s)(%65|%45|e)).*((%57|%77|w)(%48|%68|h)(%65|%45|e)(%72|%52|r)(%65|%45|e)|(%4F|%6F|o)(%6E|%4E|n)|(%41|%61|a)(%6C|%4C|l)(%6C|%4C|l)|(.*)).* [NC,OR]
```

with

```
    http://www.domain.tdl/index.php?mact=jobs,dt,default,0&dtcategory=1%5C,)%23&dtsortby=1%0D%0AUN%69ON%20S%45LECT%201,2,3,4,5,CONCAT_WS(0x203a20,%20username,%20password),7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20%20%46ROM%20tec_users--
```

note tests for

S%45LECT
UN%69ON

Also I tested on the server and saw no visable delay, but I'd love to see number put to it as it's one rule and I agree with the need to keep things light and tight.

etc.. Now if any one has a better rule that would be the chalange here.